# How to add recycler view animation like telegram?

Tags: java, android, slider, telegram, activitytransitionapi

I am currently making a chat app and i want to add a feature like telegram. As you can see [here](https://gfycat.com/meatymammothfishingcat), there is a animation in the recycler view as if i=t zooming or decreasing its size. You can also notice that animation while opening and closing the navigation drawer. I too tried to do that using [this](https://github.com/r0adkll/Slidr) but i get no animation in the recycler view. See [this](https://github.com/r0adkll/Slidr/raw/master/images/slidr_gif.gif). Actually not this but like this. I took this gif from the README of the repo. So is that possible? If so, can you please tell me a simple implementation ?

Thanks in advance and i will be waiting

Comment: I don't quite get it? Do you mean that if an item in the recyclerview is clicked, the new screen should slide in from the side? Or do you mean some different animation?

Comment: No no. I m able to add that sliding thing

Comment: If you open telegram and open a chat, then go back by sliding, you will see some animation in the recyler view

Comment: That is what I want

Answer (score 0):

Add `overridePendingTransition` in `onBackPressed()` method:

```
@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
    super.onBackPressed();
    overridePendingTransition(0, R.anim.slide_out_right);
}
```

> **res->anim->slide_out_right.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<set xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <translate
        android:duration="@android:integer/config_mediumAnimTime"
        android:fromXDelta="0"
        android:toXDelta="100%p" />
</set>
```

Comment: thanks for the answer but i want to slide like telegram. not on back pressed thing. but this one helped too !

Answer (score 0):

To me it looks like an [Activity transition](https://developer.android.com/training/transitions/start-activity) where the `translateZ` value is modified. But since the Telegram Android client is open source, we can just [take a look at it](https://github.com/DrKLO/Telegram).

It looks like the Telegram devs use a lot of custom code instead of relying on the android SDK.

The `DialogsActivity` which extends a `BaseFragment` but is neither an Android `Activity` nor an Android `Fragment` since `BaseFragment`doesn't extend any of them, has the following method for the transition:

```
    private void setSlideTransitionProgress(float progress) {
        if (SharedConfig.getDevicePerformanceClass() == SharedConfig.PERFORMANCE_CLASS_LOW) {
            return;
        }
        slideFragmentProgress = progress;
        if (fragmentView != null) {
            fragmentView.invalidate();
        }

        if (filterTabsView != null) {
            float s = 1f - 0.05f * (1f - slideFragmentProgress);
            filterTabsView.getListView().setScaleX(s);
            filterTabsView.getListView().setScaleY(s);
            filterTabsView.getListView().setTranslationX((isDrawerTransition ? AndroidUtilities.dp(4) : -AndroidUtilities.dp(4)) * (1f - slideFragmentProgress));
            filterTabsView.getListView().setPivotX(isDrawerTransition ? filterTabsView.getMeasuredWidth() : 0);
            filterTabsView.getListView().setPivotY(0);
            filterTabsView.invalidate();
        }
    }
```

Comment: thanks for the answer. but how can use this method ? where should i give the progress ? How do i know the progress of it being swiped ?